# How can I write a signed byte to a serial port in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to write signed bytes to a serial port using

SerialPort.Write() method, except that method only takes byte[] arrays of unsigned bytes,  how would i write a signed byte to the serial port?

For what I'm working on the particular command takes values from -1700 to 1700.

thanks

nightmares

Comment: A byte, signed or unsigned, doesn't support the value range you mention.  Signed bytes represent -127 to 128, while unsigned bytes represent 0 to 256.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be breaking that value up into two seperate bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial communication channel has no concept of signed or unsigned, only a concept of 1's and 0's on the wire.  It is your operating system (and ultimately your CPU architecture) that assigns a numeric value to those 1's and 0's, on both the sending and receiving side.

The value range you state cannot be represented in a byte (per my comment and your reply).  You need to understand what bit pattern the receiving device expects for a given number (is the other device [big endian or little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?), and then you can send an appropriate sequence of byte[] to represent the number you want to transmit.

If both devices have the same endianness, you can setup an array of short then copy to an array of byte like this:

```
short[] sdata = new short[] { 1, -1 };
byte[] bdata = new byte[sdata.Length * 2];

Buffer.BlockCopy(sdata, 0, bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
```

However, be sure and test for a range of values.  Especially if you are dealing with embedded devices, numeric encoding may not be exactly as on an Intel PC.

Comment: Thanks you for this Eric, that clears things up for me greatly.  When you say test for ranges you mean that the entered values are within the devices specified range?

Comment: I mean send -1700 from a test app, and make sure the device on the other end responds as if it got a -1700.  Repeat for 1700, and for 0, and for positive and negative test numbers in the range -127..128 to make sure the numeric encoding behaves as you expect.